# Cloudera CDH3 Remote Connection

Tags: connection, centos, cloudera, hue

I have the out of the box Cloudera CDH3 installed on a CentOS 6.2.  I am able to connect to the Cloudera Mananger (port 7180) or Hue (port 8088) locally, but not able to connect remotely.  Is this the OS locking down the port?  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Cloudera Manager, however have used Hue; what IP are you listening on?

If you have it configured for localhost or 127.0.0.1, then you wont be able to make the connection externally.  To fix this, you need to make it listen on whatever your external IP is.

ie /sbin/ifconfig eth0 (Or wlan0, eth1, etc).

Hope that helps.